# Recursive xmlhttp Request Not Changing

Tags: javascript, ajax, recursion, xmlhttprequest

I'm not sure what's happening here. I've hit a wall while trying to debug this.

I have the below xmlhttp request and have set it up to do a recursive call every 3 seconds to a public API. The problem I'm having is every call returns the exact same object, but if I refresh the page each time the object changes.

In other words, my xmlhttp variable is basically holding the first object it gets and never updating. I've tried nulling it before the recursive call but that didn't work. Not really sure what to do now.

```
var pullEvents = function(url){
  var xmlhttp;

  if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200){
      var res = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

      console.log(res);

      setTimeout(function(){
        pullEvents(url);
      }, 3000);
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();

};
```

Comment: This is quite likely a caching issue - what happens if you add a garbage parameter to the URL that always changes (e. g. `?_cacheBust=new Date.getTime()`)?  Also, what browser(s) display this behavior?

Comment: I'm using Chrome. Adding the garbage var to the url worked, but is there another way around this?

Comment: That is the standard way to do it on the client side, other options would involve modifications on the server side.